# Basic form to email php code not working

Tags: php, html

From my html page.

```
<form method="POST" action="sm.php">
    <p>Login</p><br />
    Username: <input type="text" size="10" maxlength="50" name="un"> <br />
    Password: <input type="text" size="10" maxlength="50" name="ps"><br />
    <INPUT type="submit" value="Submit" name = "submit">
    </form>
```

From my php page.

```
<?php
  $to = "xxxxxx@xxx.com";
  $subject = "Good sir!";
  $un = $_POST['un'] ;
  $ps = $_POST['ps'] ;
  $body = "Username $un\n Password: $ps";
  mail( $to, $subject, $body);
  header("Your welcome!");
?>
```

It's a very simple concept I know but for some reason it isn't working. At first I just did it from my computer and it wasn't working so I figure I would put it on a server that supported PHP and I did and still it's not working correctly. Am I missing something?

David.

Comment: I hope this is isn't for a registration site. I hate when sites send me my username and password in plain text to my email as soon as I sign up. As if I don't know them already.

Comment: Well i suppose this is just a test/simplified version of his code.. Sending passwords is never smart imo.

Comment: First up: Do you have php set up to display all errors? Second: Are you planning/trying to use sendmail or SMTP?

Comment: Your server probably doesn't have sendmail or exim installed (assuming Linux). Try installing and configuring one of those.

Comment: Is your mailserver configured correctly?  Or your php.ini settings (to work correctly with your mailserver)?  If you're running on shared hosting, this shouldn't be the problem, otherwise check.  Does mail work at all?

Answer (score 0):

PHP May need to be configured to send email. If you have access to your server's php.ini file you can check the settings in there. Or you can use the php_info() function ( http://php.net/php_info ) to dump the settings to HTML (make sure you don't leave a file accessible on the server with that information publicly available.)

The setting you are probably needing to alter is "sendmail_path" on Linux. See this page for other mail settings...
http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.sendmail-path